# Im aware im trying to get data for multiple accounts but where can i specify that rather than receiving this error in R?

Tags: r, google-ads-api, gargle

```
 library(rgoogleads)
 library(gargle)

 token <- token_fetch()

 token

gads_auth(email = 'xx@gmail.com'
Authentication complete.

     ad_group_report <- gads_get_report(
       resource    = "ad_group",
       fields      = c("ad_group.campaign",
                       "ad_group.id",
                       "ad_group.name",
                       "ad_group.status",
                       "metrics.clicks",
                       "metrics.cost_micros"),
       date_from   = "2021-01-08",
       date_to     = "2021-01-10",
       where       = "ad_group.status = 'ENABLED'",
       order_by    = c("metrics.clicks DESC", "metrics.cost_micros")
     )
i Multi account request
! The request you sent did not return any results, check the entered parameters and repeat the opposition.
```

Why do I receive this error? I have never received it in `Radwords` package. Where do I mention the argument for the multiple accounts?
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgoogleads/rgoogleads.pdf

Comment: Please be sure not to copy and paste code that you've already run in the console. Someone will have to remove all of the `+` and `>` to be able to run the code.

Comment: @AndrewGillreath-Brown thanks i made the edits. Please help with solution if possible